# mySQL efficiency with inner join queries

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have two tables, both with about 1,000,000 rows.

Here is the question I am trying to get mySQL to solve:

- return all record_ids from table_a where that id matches the cat_id in table_b, but only for customer_id 654 (customer_id exists in both tables).

First off I tried this with the following statement:

```
SELECT record_id from `table_a` where customer_id="654" and record_id in
(SELECT cat_id from `table_b` where cat_id="654");
```

This is the most logical looking one to me, as it's more at my coding level.  But this query took 2 minutes to run.  So I tried to re-write it using:

```
SELECT record_id from `table_a` where 
customer_id = "654" and exists (SELECT cat_id FROM `table_b` where
table_b.customer_id = "654" and
table_a.record_id= table_b.cat_id 
group by record_id having count(*) > 1);
```

This took 22 seconds to run.

I tried another way as well:

```
SELECT table_a.record_id from table_a
INNER JOIN table_b ON (table_a.record_id = table_b.cat_id)
WHERE table_a.customer_id = "654" and table_b.customer_id= "654"
GROUP BY table_a.record_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This one takes 19.5 seconds to run.

I'm wondering if my third attempt is the most efficient way to ask this question, or as I'm hoping, there is a more efficient way to run these.

Here is mySQL's execution path for the last two queries:

[image]

On **table_a**, I have the following indices:

```
KEY `rc` (`record_id`,`customer_id`)
KEY `test` (`record_id`,`customer_id`),  
KEY `test2` (`record_id`,`customer_id`),  
KEY `cust` (`customer_id`)
```

On **table_b**, I have the following indices:

```
KEY `rc` (`cat_id, `customer_id`)
```

There are duplicates that I made on accident and I haven't gotten around to deleting them, (not sure if that impacts performance):

Comment: To help you, we need to know what indexes you have on those tables.

Comment: MySQL is notoriously bad at optimizing `WHERE col IN (SELECT col FROM table2)`. I always use a `JOIN`.

Comment: To get the best results, you need to: (1) Make sure that if table is majorly insert, stick with MyISAM, (2) Create index on searched columns, (3) Implement JOIN correctly where Primary Table is on left. That should return quick results.

Comment: Why are you indexing in pairs? Please show all uses of PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE, since they also add indexes.

Comment: Why does your first SQL query test b.cat_id = 654 instead of b.customer_id = 654? Is customer_id required to be the same in both tables? (Your English version is not clear. And your SQL versions don't agree. So it's not clear what you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT record_id from `table_a`
> where customer_id="654"
> and record_id in
>     (SELECT cat_id from `table_b` where cat_id="654");
> ```

The [meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27682724/3404097) of a `JOIN` is the AND of the meanings of its arguments. `ON` and `WHERE` both AND in a conditon. You want rows where (using obvious aliases):
    customer [a.customer_id] ...
AND customer [b.cat_id] ...
AND [a.customer_id] = 654 AND [b.cat_id] = 654
AND [a.record_id] = [b.cat_id]

```
SELECT a.record_id
FROM `table_a` a JOIN `table_b` b
WHERE a.customer_id = 654 AND b.cat_id = 654
AND a.record_id = b.cat_id
```

(In standard SQL ( `INNER` ) `JOIN` needs an `ON`. So you could `CROSS JOIN` or replace `WHERE` by `ON`.)

As a comment says, MySQL has historically not been very good at optimizing. But it is constantly improving. `IN` has been notoriously slow, even when it is [equivalent to other more optimized expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html). You may get better performance by explicitly equating the `id`s first in an `ON`:

```
SELECT a.record_id
FROM `table_a` a JOIN `table_b` b
ON a.record_id = b.cat_id
AND a.customer_id = 654 AND b.cat_id = 654
```

Declare each of those fields as `PK` or `UNIQUE NOT NULL` if it is (which implicitly adds an index), otherwise add an index on it. MySQL unadorned `KEY` is a synonym for `INDEX` when not in a column declaration, which does not tell the database that a column set is unique. Yes, uniqueness affects performance, so give your tables their proper rows and declare and enforce any uniqueness by `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE`.

If you make the `id`s `INT` then the DBMS only needs to go to the index, not the data.

(Also, [read the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) re keys, indices and [optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-optimization.html). Use `EXPLAIN`.)

Answer (score 1):

Based (only) on your query i think the better query could be :

```
 SELECT table_a.record_id from table_a
 INNER JOIN table_b ON (table_a.record_id = table_b.cat_id)
 WHERE table_a.customer_id = "654" and table_b.customer_id= "654"
 GROUP BY table_a.record_id
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

the correct index could be in   table a  only this:

```
KEY cust_and_rec (customer_id, record_id)
```

in table b only

```
KEY cust (custmer_id)
```

In the index you show in your question seem `rc, test and test2` are the same and not  so selective like the inverse (customer_id is the most selective value in your query )

index rc on table b seem not useful for your purpose.